# How can I change the maximum number of logged-in users in ADB2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a login screen with ADB2C.
I has two questions.

1:I want to limit the number of simultaneously active users to 150.(Maximum number of simultaneous connections)
　Where can I set it up?

2:I want to display an error when the configured limit of active users is exceeded.
Where can I set this up as well?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AFAIK, In case of azure ad B2C ,limiting concurrent active users is
   not yet supported.

   According to [token-issuance-rate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-user-flow#token-issuance-rate)

   > Each type of User Flow provides a unique user experience and will
   > consume a different number of requests. **The token issuance rate of a
   > User Flow is dependent on the number of requests consumed by both the
   > static and dynamic endpoints.**

   [image]

   [Reference for userconsumption related limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-user-flow#userconsumption-related-limits)
2. If you already knew the users characteristics and want to restrict
   users based on that , the recommended way to control the access in
   Azure B2C is [defining custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow) and check the claims in
   token. If the expected claim is included, you allow the user to
   continue.
3. You can check and handle the possibility of [microsoft graph
   throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) from this link

   > **Throttling limits the number of concurrent calls to a service** to
   > prevent overuse of resources. Microsoft Graph is designed to handle a
   > high volume of requests.  When throttling occurs, Microsoft Graph
   > returns HTTP status code 429 (Too many requests)

**References:**

1. [azure active-directory-b2c service limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-user-flow#userconsumption-related-limits)
2. [b2c userflow identity-protection-investigate-risk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-protection-investigate-risk?pivots=b2c-user-flow)